# How do I Launch Android/iOS App on Webpage Load

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to figure out how to launch an app upon loading a website. The idea is, a user clicks a link in an email or text, and it brings them to a webpage, witch will redirect them to either the app if they have it installed, or the webpage if they dont have the app, or are using a computer. I have this script here

```
launchApp = function () {
    window.location = "<app launch url>";
    setTimeout(launchWebpage, 25);
}
 
launchWebpage = function () {
    window.location = "<Webpage Url>";
}

$( window ).on( "load",launchApp);
```

This loads the web page, but does not launch the app.
If I get rid of the bottom window on load section, and instead call my launchApp function directly from a button, like

```
<button id="test" onclick="launchApp()">Button</button>
```

everything works. It launches the app if installed, and if not, the webpage loads. How can I get this to work automatically instead of having to press the button?

Comment: For Android - https://developer.android.com/training/app-links

Comment: The app link works fine, thats not the problem. It just only works when pressing the button, and not automatically on page load.

Comment: From the answer to that question, it is not possible, however, I have seen examples of it working, such as https://nyulangone.app/testresult

Comment: Unfortunately I'm unable to see that link! Are there any clues there as to how it is done?

Comment: Not that I could figure out. That link also automatically opens the google play store if the user does not have the app installed, when if I tried to have it automatically open the play store, it would just open the web page, while if I did the same thing, but triggered by a button, it would open the play store itself.

Comment: Looking in the network logs on both my test site, and the one I found that works, mine has a status code of 304, while the working one has a status code of 307. Could that be whats changing it, and how would I do that?

Comment: `304 - Not Modified` Usually used for cached resources and `307 - Temporary Redirect` Essentially the same as `302 - Temporary Redirect` but do not change method (POST will redirect as POST, etc.)